# Delete from Parent table procedure in PLSQL

Tags: plsql, parent-child, procedure

I'm tasked with deleting entries from a `parent table` which means I need to get rid of the corresponding entries in the `child table`.  I need to do this in a `procedure` and is based off of the `primary key` of the `parent table`.  As of right now I am just confused on what `input parameters` I need.  This is what I have so far:

```
procedure sps_delete_patientmedrecs_det  (
  p_parentPK_in   in parent_table.parentPK%type,
  p_err_code_out  out number,
  p_err_msg_out   out varchar2)
delete from child_table
  where child_table.childFK = p_parentPK_in;

delete from parent_table
  where parent_table.parent.parentPK = p_parentPK_in;
end;
```

As of right now I dont think this would work because I dont think the `procedure` would know what the `child foreign key` is.  I thought of doing a `select` statement but then I'm confused on the `input paremeters` would be since I am only getting p_parentPK_in.  Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Also as a footnote, `DELETE CASCADE` isnt in the picture.

Comment: What are you doing with the err_code parameters? Just use standard PL/SQL exceptions. :) You wouldn't do that in Java, so why it is any different in PL/SQL?

Comment: The company I work for uses it differently, I just didnt show what they were doing in the procedure.

Comment: One I used to work for also did that. When talking to the project leader, he was just not aware of custom exceptions. Changing everything is another matter of course, but I'm confident for his next project he'll do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, that worked.  I just added another begin before the second delete.